# There does not exist a continuous surjective function from $S^1$ onto $\mathbb R$.

Tags: general-topology

How can we go about proving that there does not exist any continuous surjective function from $S^1$ onto $\mathbb R$. Here $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$.

If it were bijective function, we could have just invoked the result that continuous image of a connected set is connected. But as it is only surjective, removing one point from the domain could still leave the image connected.

Comment: Do you know about compactness?

Comment: $S_1$ is compact.

Comment: **1.** As a interesting question you can also try to show that there is no injective continuous map from $S^1 \to \mathbb R^1$.(Infact $1$ can be replaced with any natural number but the proof for general $n$ is bit involved). **2.** Also continuous image of any connected space is connected.(Don't require any bijectivity) but this result does not tell you anything as $\mathbb R$ is connected.

Comment: @ArpitKansal I was going to invoke connected space argument by removing one point from $S^1$ and restricting the function to the new subset. Removing one point from $\mathbb R$ would leave it disconnected.
I will try to prove the first part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$S^1$ is compact and $\mathbb R$ is not.

Comment: (and the continuous image of a compact set is compact)

Comment: It's been very long since I have done a Topology course. Now that I look at it, I realise that it was a very basic question. Thank you!

Comment: @Prince No problem.